# JAVA: Not a statement - for calling 'long'?

Tags: java, methods, long-integer

I have written the following piece of code.

```
public long secFromMidnight()
{
     long seconds_from_midnight = (this._hour * SEC_IN_HOUR) + (this._minute * SEC_IN_MIN) + (this._second);
     return seconds_from_midnight;
}

public int difference(Time1 other)
{
    long 1stSEC = null;
    long 2ndSEC = null;
    1stSEC= this.secFromMidnight();
    2ndSEC = other.secFromMidnight();
    return (int)(1stSEC - 2ndSEC);
}
```

When I try to compile, i get an error of "Not a Statement" for "long 1stSEC = null";

Why is this happening?
I was able to declare a long variable in the method before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename this variables with the right names and not initialize them with `null` but with `0` for example like this:

```
 long sEC1st = 0;
 long sEC2nd = 0;
```

> Using ALL uppercase letters are primarily used to identify constant variables. Remember that variable names are case-sensitive. You cannot use a java keyword (reserved word) for a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

A variable's **name** cannot start with a **number**.

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>   identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>   digits, **beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>   underscore character "*".*** The convention, however, is to always begin
>   your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "".

[Java variables' naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Plus, `long` is a **primitive** type, hence you cannot assign `null` to a `long` variable. Set it to **0** instead.